# Select by expression and remove points

Tags: qgis, point, select

How do I select points by expression and delete these selected points?

Is it possible to do this inside the modeler with a tool?

The selection by expression works fine but do I have to set all the selected points to NULL?

Comment: In QGIS go to the edit mode, select the points and simply cancel them

Comment: I need to do this in with modeler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use a **custom script** in your modeler to delete selected features. You can create one via:

`Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script`

Then use something like the following:

```
##Example=name
##Layer=vector

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
ids = [f.id() for f in layer.selectedFeatures()]
layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids)
```

You can then insert this into your model and select the output of the `Select by expression` tool as the input:

[image: Script in modeler]

This should delete all selected features **from your chosen layer**.

Comment: It works fine! But if I have selected more than 1 feature it doesnt delete anything....sorry I'm not used to python scripting.

Comment: @Pimpel - Sorry, my fault. Fixed the code so it should now delete all selected features =)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanx.

Comment: @Pimpel - Most welcome, glad it works ;)

Comment: Hi @Pimpel, thank you for sharing this! Would you be able to enlighten me on how to specify an output for this script? Trying to integrate it as a step in a model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in order to complete the process in case your are using this as intermediary step do next: 
Select within the parent algorithm the following tool within the model. You should see and schema like this.

[image]