# How to delete features selected by expression using graphical modeler in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I can't find an algorithm for deleting features (points), so I can't delete features in the graphical modeler.

I found related information ([Select by expression and remove points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193970/select-by-expression-and-remove-points)). However, I want to know how to use QGIS3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to delete features in the modeler, in this case use the **extract by expression** and put an expression that generates the opposite result of your current selection.

This will result in a layer with the features that match the expression you entered.

Therefore unwanted features were not deleted but ignored.

Comment: I did not notice. The solution is simple. Thank you for your kindness.